# jQuery Find Next Anchor Element and Hide it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a Page with repeating anchors

```
<div id ="div1">
 <a class='button id='edit1'>Edit</>
<a class='button id='Close'>Close</a>
</div>
<div id ="div2">
 <a class='button id='edit2'>Edit</>
<a class='button id='Close'>Close</a>
</div>
<div id ="div3">
 <a class='button id='edit3'>Edit</>
<a class='button id='Close'>Close</a>
</div>
```

when i click Edit Anchor I need to find the next Close anchor with in the div and  hide is.

This is how i tried it.

```
var anchors = $("a[class='button']");
    var position = anchors.index($('a[id=edit' + ID + ']'));
    var next = anchors.get(position + 1);
**next.hide();** // Can i hide like this.
```

any suggestions?

if you have noticed my close anchor will have a common id so i can be specific with ID

More Details Can i do it in a function

```
function abc(id){ 
$('a[id=edit' + id + ']').next('.change').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id ="div1">
 <a class='button edit' id='edit1'>Edit</a>
<a class='button Close'>Close</a>
</div>
```

add an `edit` class

```
$("a.edit").click(function(){
$("a.Close").show(); //show the previously hidden element
$(this).next("a").hide(); //hide the intended one
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aGfct/23/)**

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WtHnW/)

HTML:

```
<div id ="div1">
 <a class='button edit' id='edit1'>Edit</a>
<a class='button close' id='close1'>Close</a>
</div>
<div id ="div2">
 <a class='button edit' id='edit2'>Edit</a>
<a class='button close' id='close2'>Close</a>
</div>
<div id ="div3">
 <a class='button edit' id='edit3'>Edit</a>
<a class='button close' id='close3'>Close</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.close').hide();
});
```

Comment: I would opt for using: `$(this).siblings('.close').hide();` instead of next in case the order of the elements change.

Comment: can i do with a function, because i don't have  a click event for this. i am calling  function . function abc(id){ $('a[id=edit' + id + ']').next('.change').hide();} can i do like this

Answer (score 1):

Use the next() function in jquery

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
     $(this).next(".close").hide();
});
```

And btw you cannot have the same id on several items. Use class instead.